# Shell Script -- Search and Edit line by line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, edit

I'm trying to write a shell script that could first read a script file. Then search out lines that contain my selected 'keywords' then add some words at the end of the line. Those 'keywords' only appear at the begging of the line.

This is what I have done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while IFS='' read -r line; do
echo "$line"
done < "filename"
```

I tried if I can separate a line into several fields, but I failed. Cuz I wanted to then use 'if' to do a search. But it seems like the 'read' command could only save the whole line into a variable.

Here is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while IFS='' read -r f1 f2 f3; do
echo "$f1"
done < "filename"
```

but its output is the same thing.

Anyone could give me some advice?

Before:

```
Final=$(date -d "2016-12-15 14:00" "+%j")
while true ; do
  Today=$(date "+%j")
  Days=$((Final - Today))
  if (( Days >= 14 )) ; then
    echo party
  elif (( Days >= 2 )) ; then
    echo study
  elif (( Days == 1 )) ; then
    for Count in 1 2 3
      do
      echo panic
    done
  else
    break
  fi
  sleep 8h
done
```

After:

```
Final=$(date -d "2016-12-15 14:00" "+%j")
while true ; do   # loop 1
  Today=$(date "+%j")
  Days=$((Final - Today))
  if (( Days >= 14 )) ; then   # selection 1
    echo party
  elif (( Days >= 2 )) ; then
    echo study
  elif (( Days == 1 )) ; then
    for Count in 1 2 3   # loop 2
      do
      echo panic
    done   # loop 2
  else
    break
  fi   # selection 1
  sleep 8h
done   # loop 1
```

Comment: Do you know about `grep`? `while read -r f1 f2 f3; do` should do for splitting on whitespace. Only change `IFS` if you want a different delimiter.

Comment: Also use `done < "$filename"`.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to do? Especially the file before and after the action.

Comment: How can I use grep to make this?

Comment: Sure, Beta. I edited the question. I added the example on it

Comment: @IvanChak: Your latest edit too doesn't make sense too. Provide a minimal input and an expected output for the same.

Comment: @Inian want to add comment at the end to label those loop and if function.

Comment: Let say the first while occur I labeled it #loop 1

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the given formatting of lines left intact, we have to `read` the line as a whole first (as you did with `IFS='' read -r line`) and thereafter separate it to check the command keywords.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
while IFS='' read -r line   # read whole line
do  set -- $line            # split to fields
    case $1 in
    while|for) comment="    # loop $((++loop))";;
         done) comment="    # loop $((loop--))";;
           if) comment="    # selection $((++slct))";;
           fi) comment="    # selection $((slct--))";;
            *) comment=;;
    esac
    echo "$line$comment"
done <"$filename"
```